# Is it possible to archive and transfer replays in Street Fighter 4?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I have SSF4AE for PC and I want to store my old replays, so I can watch them later or send them to a friend.

Is this possible like in Starcraft 2?

- I want to record and save a replay.
- Then I want to copy and send the replay/file to a friend.
- He opens it and is able to watch it on his computer.

I know there are online replay channels, but they seem very limited. A common technique seems to be to create a video and use that instead of replays. But they are very big and it does not scale well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to backup the whole replay directory which is located in:

```
C:\Users\<accountname>\Documents\CAPCOM\SUPERSTREETFIGHTERIV\<randomnumber>
```

`<randomnumber>` looks like `e00002864b3dcd76`

Then you can copy it back to watch some old replays, but you cannot copy only one replay file, because the save.dat requires the replays to stay the same.

This means if you want a replay later you have to follow these steps:

- Copy the `<randomnumber>` folder to `C:\Savegames\2012-11-26\<randomnumber>`
- If you want to watch a replay backup your current by copying the `<randomnumber>` folder to `C:\Savegames\current\<randomnumber>`
- Copy `C:\Savegames\2012-11-26\<randomnumber> to C:\Users\<accountname>\Documents\CAPCOM\SUPERSTREETFIGHTERIV\<randomnumber>` and watch the replay
- Afterwards restore your folder from `C:\Savegames\current\<randomnumber>`